# Mouse support for GNU Readline

Tags: bash, terminal, mouse, readline

Is it possible to get programs using GNU Readline (e.g. Bash, the Python REPL, or anything else that responds to `~/.inputrc`) to let you edit the current line using the mouse? For example, I’d like to be able to click at a specific place in the line to move the cursor, or select a region of text.

I suspect the answer is “no, this is not supported”, given that I have found no useful Google results about Readline (the best I’ve found is mouse support in ZSH, which is nice because I do use it as my shell but it doesn’t help with other Readline programs), but I also haven’t been able to confirm that.

The closest I've found to this kind of thing in arbitrary Readline programs is that some terminal emulators attempt to detect when Readline is active and emit arrow-key sequences on click. I'd rather have this handled by Readline if possible, both because I expect it would do a better job and because I like the terminal emulator I currently use, which doesn't support that.

Answer (score 5):

Does that work ? It should print escaped sequences on your terminal when using the mouse

```
echo -e "\e[?1000;1006;1015h" # Enable tracking
```

If it works : test my script on [github](https://github.com/tinmarino/mouse_xterm/blob/master/mouse.sh)

Details : Read my answer in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55437976/2544873)

Comment: This looks like it would work in Bash but would need to be re-written for each Readline-enabled program, is that right? And I don't think Python for example even has a way to programmatically set the point.

Comment: True : __works only on bash and ipython__. I don't know why ipython but I guess because it has been well written. I may improved that in the future wih only modifying .inputrc so it would work on perl reply for example.

Comment: @DanielH : It has already been written for python : run : `ipython --TerminalInteractiveShell.mouse_support=True` look there : https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/key_binding/bindings/mouse.py